# How to use css and js file in the webview of vscode extension sidebar

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode-extensions

I want to create a webview in sidebar so that I can make the content richer.

I use `vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider` to regist the webview, and I don't want to write html content in string, so I decide to create html, js and css file like a html project.

I create a webview folder to store html file and when I regist webview, I use `vscode.workspace.fs.readDirectory` to read the content of html file, and set two tags like #css, #js in it. After get html string, I use the replace method to replace css and js tag to a external file reference script.

For example

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    #css
</head>
<body>
    <div>Dom</div>
    #js
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// Js
this.htmlContent = this.htmlContent
    .replace(/(#css)/, this.cssUri?`<link href="${webviewView.webview.asWebviewUri(this.cssUri!)}" rel="stylesheet />`:'')
    .replace(/(#js)/, this.jsUri?`<script type="text/javascript" src="${webviewView.webview.asWebviewUri(this.jsUri!)}"></script>`:'');
```

Finally

```js
// in resolveWebviewView method
webviewView.webview.html = this.htmlContent;
```

Now I set some styles and modify a dom node, but it has some issues.

I use `document.querySelector('').innerHTML` to modify the content of a dom, but it's failed. And when I set style of a tag, it's succeed.But when I set the style of a class, it's failed.

[set the style of div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP1oV.png)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDS6u.png)

[set the style of class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvDJk.png)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpccW.png)

- Did I use wrong ways to import css and js?

My project address:https://github.com/wangyige0701/vscodeCustomExtension